# MassTransit - Using in Azure... Topics, Events and Bounded Context

Tags: masstransit

We're using MassTransit (locally using RabbitMQ, deployed in Azure using Service Bus).

As a hypothetical question, and potentially, a wider domain modelling question, it seems, MassTransit has develop-by-convention approaches, which is great.

But, what that seems to do is create a 1:1 relationship with a topic and a given Event 'type'; for example, assuming the service of 'foo', we'd have foo_created, foo_updated, foo_deleted, all with distinct Topics up in Azure.

So, my question, lets scale this up, and have more and more 'domains'; "Foo", "Bar", etc...

Would it not be better to configure MassTransit somehow, so that events for a given domain, are contained within a bounded context in a Topic - therefore, having all events to do with that domain on a single topic (for that domain). So a "foo" topic, a "bar" topic, etc, etc...

This way, future subscribers to domain events would listen to the topic as a whole, receiving all events to do with that domain, instead of constantly having to make sure they are having subscriptions while new events are added into the domain (as development progresses)

Just wondered everyone else's convention here and experience... how do you decide what a topic 'contains'?

As standard, MassTransit configures a topic per specific event when using with Service Bus and Azure.